# How to merge the mirror modifier correctly?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, mirror

[image]

So I am mirroring this object so that it merges with it's "reflection", but it does not come out clean. As you can see it is pinched and there is also a gap in there. How can I fix this? I have been having this problem for a while.
Thanks!

Comment: Also make sure your object truly starts at the object origin.

Answer (score 7):

you need to use a lower value for 'merge limit' parameter to lower the distance before vertices are automatically merged.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue and found moving "Mirror" above "Subsurf" modifier fixed it.